# Which part of systemd starts the module-load service?

Tags: linux, systemd

I'm trying to understand how the systemd service, mainly `systemd-module-load.service`, is started in Linux. I looked at the `main()` routine (in systemd's `src/core/main.c`), but I couldn't find any direct references to systemd unit/services.

Comment: Did you try `systemd-analyze` (to have data about your latest boot) and/or `systemd --test --system --unit=multi-user.target` (that will show what is run in order to get to multi-user.target, without running anything really)

Answer (score 1):

`systemd-modules-load.service` is specified as a dependency of `sysinit.target`.  You can search for / confirm such dependencies:

```
$ systemctl list-dependencies --reverse systemd-modules-load.service
systemd-modules-load.service
● └─sysinit.target
●   ├─abrt-ccpp.service
...
```

The output is not necessarily very convenient, because it proceeds to list a large number of units which depend on `sysinit.target`, in alphabetical order.  At least this suggests `sysinit.target` is quite important :).  We can ask which part of systemd starts `sysinit.target`, and I think this reference will answer your question -

> When systemd starts up the system, it will activate all units that are
>          dependencies of `default.target` (as well as recursively all dependencies
>          of these dependencies). Usually, `default.target` is simply an alias of
>          graphical.target or multi-user.target, depending on whether the system
>          is configured for a graphical UI or only for a text console. To enforce
>          minimal ordering between the units pulled in, a number of well-known
>          target units are available, as listed on [systemd.special(7)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html).

- this quote is followed by a chart, which illustrates that `sysinit.target` is an indirect dependency of `multi-user.target`, and hence also of `graphical.target`.

See: `man bootup` or https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/bootup.html

---

> I looked at the main() routine (in systemd's src/core/main.c), but I couldn't find any direct references to systemd unit/services

There are references to specific units within `src/core/`.  They are indirected through `SPECIAL_` defines from `src/basic/special.h`.  This includes:

```
#define SPECIAL_DEFAULT_TARGET "default.target"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear exactly what you are looking for.

The binary `/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load` is one run by the `systemd-modules-load.service` that does the actual kernel loading.